# Graphical element for range between two elements

Tags: website-design, design-principles, conceptualization

I have two long sentences. One describes a product in very simple configuration and one the same product in extremely complex configuration. I would like to place them on a website next to each other and put some graphical element between or around them that will imply that the uses of the product can fit anywhere between these two boundaries.

Does anyone have any ida what that element could be?

Comment: Most of the time these sorts of things text is just used to describe the difference. For example "simple configuration" and "detailed example" or something like that.

Comment: Will need visual example.